# How can a Svelte component declare its props dynamically?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

My svelte component has a bunch of props:

```
export let color;
export let width;
export let orientation;
export let highlighted;
export let showFocus;
export let animate;
// and 10 more
```

They're also reactive in this very simple manner:

```
$: update({color: color});
$: update({width: width});
$: update({orientation: orientation});
// ...
```

Is there any way to declare these props, and preferrably the reactive statements, dynamically? I'd like to just list an array with all the props. Keeping them in a key-value object is not an option as far as I understand since I want them to be accessible via `<MyComponent color={...}>` and `myComponent.color`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest possible thing would be using [`$$props` or `$$restProps`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-attributes-and-props) instead, these objects contain all properties/all not explicitly defined properties.

It will *not* give you accessors on the instance, but you can set the values directly as attributes in the markup. You also cannot generate reactive statements from this (unless you do not mind `update` being called redundantly for every property, even if only one of them changed.

---

A more radical approach would be writing a Svelte pre-processor that generates the necessary code. This is probably not hard to do but will confuse language tooling that currently does not operate on the processed result.

```js
// svelte.config.js

/** @type {import('svelte/types/compiler/preprocess').PreprocessorGroup} */
const generateProperties = {
    script: ({ content, filename }) => {
        // somehow define what properties to generate in the component and
        // generate relevant code from that here

        return {
            code: generatedProperties + '\n' + content,
        };
    }
}

const config = {
    preprocess: [
        generateProperties,
    ],
};

export default config;
```